# Earth Engine: Mosaic 2 collections

Tags: merge, google-earth-engine, mosaic

Given that an area of interest is partially cloud covered, how can you mosaic two separate collections to get a single cloud free mosaic?

Given I have a S2 image over a study area, that has a cloudy eastern half:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-03-01')
.filterBounds(geometry5)
```

and imagery over the same region from a previous date that has a cloudy western half:

```js
var collection2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2016-11-13', '2016-12-23')
.filterBounds(geometry4)
```

Is there a way to mosaic the data together to get a single collection/dataset?

This is a straightforward task with gdal but I can't find it in the Earth Engine documentation.

As a visual example:

I have this collection:

[image: cloud free western collection]

and this separate collection:

[image: cloud free eastern collection]

and I want to merge/mosaic them into a single collection:

[image: Final complete mosaic]

Comment: What is the mosaicing strategy you want? Min/Max pixel value? image 2 on top of image 1? Mean value in overlapping areas?

Comment: Ideally image 1 on top of image 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both dates you provide the collections contain multiple images over the sundarban region. A *ImageCollection* is a spatial as well as temporal collection of images. To display them you have to reduce them to an image first.

In your case it looks like you tried to display the collection, in which case GEE will take the first non-zero value for each pixel stack in your collection. You can recreate that by using the `.firstNonNull()` reducer.

```js
var date1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-03-01')
.filterBounds(sundarban1)
.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
.clip(sundarban1)

var date2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2016-11-13', '2016-12-23')
.filterBounds(sundarban2)
.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
.clip(sundarban2)
```

The result are two images, each containing data for the different polygons you've drawn (in my case sundarban1 and sundarban2).

To merge both into a single image with a similar logic as GDAL you can use the `.mosaic` operator. The last image in the list will be on top.

```js
var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([date2, date1]).mosaic()
```

The complete script on GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e61e918ddbfac828ccf313f186a64e24

Comment: Awesome. In a step I didn't include I did indeed reduce them to get images. I did play around with the '.mosaic()' call but wasn't sure of the syntax!